# Why can't I connect to Access database using Talend DI? NullPointerException

Tags: ms-access, talend, ucanaccess, data-integration

I'm trying to move data from an Access database to a Microsoft SQL server database. I created my connection to the Access database. When I verify the connection, it tells me it works fine. But when I'm running my Job, I'm getting the following error:

```
 Exception in component tAccessInput_1 (myDB)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
    at cftmc.myJob_0_1.myDB.tAccessInput_1Process(myDB.java:1168)
    at cftmc.myJob_0_1.myDB.runJobInTOS(myDB.java:2050)
    at cftmc.myJob_0_1.myDB.main(myDB.java:1753)
```

I'm reading my database with MS Access 2007 but it seems like the database was created with MS Access 97.
Btw I asked on Talendforge already a few days ago but I still have no answer.

Here is the connection:
[image: Here is the connection]

Here is the job:
[image: Here is the job]

Comment: NullPointerException could be for a number of reasons. Please [edit] your question and add a picture of the connection and the job workflow.

Comment: Done. I'm sorry I had to remove the Talendforge link since I'm new to stackoverflow, I can't post more than 2 links. As you can see on the attached pictures, it's a very simple job. There isn't any data conversion or anything.

Comment: Could you change the last picture to one where the database access component is selected?

Comment: In the supplementary parameters you might try using `memory=false;showSchema=true`.

Comment: I changed the last picture as you requested.

Comment: @GordThompson I tried to add the `showSchema=true` in my parameters and now I'm getting a new error: `Exception in component tAccessInput_1 (test)
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: jet format 'VERSION_3' does not support writing for C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Théo\CFTMC\Data\dataself.mdb`